# changes to /etc/bash.bashrc not permanent

Tags: bashrc, auto-completion

After a recent upgrade to 12.04, auto tab completion was disable in /etc/bash.bashrc.  I uncommented the following lines:

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

I tried to then run `source /etc/bash.bashrc` and `. /etc/bash.bashrc` but neither reloaded the config.  They just gave me the error `-sh: 1: source: not found`.  Typing in simply `bash` did seem to work and enabled auto tab completion.  However after logging out of the server and then logging back in, I find that auto tab completion is not working again and the only way to get it working is to type `bash` again.

Anyone know what I need to do to make this change permanent?

EDIT:

I just realized that when I initially ssh into the server, it just says `$`.  After running the `bash` command, it then says `username@machinename$`.  Not sure if this has anything to do with my problem or not...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`source` isn't an executable command, it's a bash builtin. It seems that your login shell isn't bash (it might be `sh`).

You can change your shell with

```
chsh
```

Enter `/bin/bash` there. You should be able to use `source` afterwards.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly the problem.  Running chsh showed that sh was set as the default.